# VBA If file not found

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I don't do a lot of VBA.  I have some code:

```
If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
    Range("A13").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Range("H2").Value
End If
```

Simple.  Changes Comment BG image based on criteria in cell A13, plugs in a file/path generated by H2.  However...

Sometimes the file/path doesn't exist for what's in H2 (as H2 is created based on user input/selection).

I've tried this:

```
If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
    Range("A13").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Range("H2").Value
Else
    Range("A13").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Range("H6").Value
End If
```

Where H6 is another generated file/path to "NOIMAGE.jpg", which would be a constant for any entry that doesn't have an associated image.  It doesn't like that either.

I can't find an else expression that will do what it needs before the method tried to run/find what's in H2.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A13").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Range("H2").Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Range("A13").Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Range("H6").Value
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End If
```

Comment: Apparently it's called, "Error Handling".  Who knew?  Thank ya, sir.